# Masking padded values impacts LSTM prediction

Tags: python, lstm, mask, seq2seq

I need to do seq2seq prediction with LSTM. As I have different lengths of sequences in term of timesteps,  I padded values with 9999.0 and then I used a mask layer in order to ignore 9999 value. However, my model doesn't ignore them and predict padding values too.
I used the code below.

```
verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 70, 16
n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2], y_train.shape[2]
print(n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs )
# define model
model_lstm = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=9999.,input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features)))
model_lstm.add(LSTM(200, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features)))
model_lstm.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model_lstm.add(Dense(n_outputs))
model_lstm.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    # fit network
model_lstm.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
y_predict = model.predict(x_test)
```

#### Example of Input

[image]

#### Example of Output

[image]

#### Example of estimated output - y_test -

[image]

As you can see, my model predict values very far from the expected. What do you suggest me to do ? Is the mask layer who bias the model ?

Answer (score 0):

The mask gets propagated through the network to every next layer as long as they know how to handle it. After your LSTM layer, the mask stops propagating because LSTM layer has a default argument of return_sequences=False (the time dimension gets crashed). You can verify that by running:

```
for i, l in enumerate(model.layers):
    print(f'layer {i}: {l}')
    print(f'\thas input mask: {l.input_mask}')
    print(f'\thas output mask: {l.output_mask}')
```